# ASP.NET MVC3 dropdown JQuery change event

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have two drodowns in y cshtml one is Manufacture and another one is Series i have to bind series drop down based o Manufaturer drop down change evnt Dynamically . I have bind Manufacture Drop down dynamically and use following code to bind Series it won't bind 
in my cs.Html

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.6.4.js"></script>
 <script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.6.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#CompProducts").change(function () {

        var selection = $("#CompProducts").val();
        var dataToSend = {
            paymentType: selection

        };
        alert(dataToSend);
        alert(dataToSend);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            url: "MobileHome/GetCompSeries", 
            data: dataToSend,
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Drop downs are define like

```
        <li>Competitor:
                @Html.DropDownList("CompProducts", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["Manufacturer"], "-- Select --", new
           {
               onchange = "javascript:ChangeLocalSite(this.value);"
           })
            </li>
            <li id="Li1" runat="server">Series:
                <select id="iLevel" name="iLevel">
                    <option value="-1">-- Select --</option>
                </select>
            </li>
```

please help me how to bind series drop down when change the Manufacturer Drop down

Comment: show your action GetCompSeries

Comment: This is my action  public JsonResult GetCompSeries(string Manc)
        {


            return Json(new { agent = "sample html" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

Answer (score 0):

You need add jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js

Comment: I have added  jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js but i ssue is not reolve

Answer (score 0):

```
data: JSON.stringify(dataToSend)
```

should work